# Uploading android application to google play error

Tags: android, google-play

I'm android developer and I have google play account, Yesterday I uploaded 
new application to google play store , after one day application uploaded and published successfully, but when  I click on application  link to view it in web browser this message appears "`We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server.`"

Url : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ahmed.elessae

Any  help ?

Comment: Can you share the url? Or the name of your app?

Comment: url  : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ahmed.elessae
app name : العسائى

Comment: Gives me 'Item Not Found'. Is your app available in all countries for download? Can you search for through the Playstore app and not the web browser?

Comment: Check your Email to see any violation happened..

Comment: i changed the country target  and select all countries and i  will wait few hours